# SQL result not english characters

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, iso-8859-1

I always work with MySQL but in but I am forced now to work with SQL Server and I am lost. I just want to get a row in spanish and I can't make it work. Here is the code, hopefully everything makes sense.

```
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=$server;Database=$database;", $user, $password);
$sql="SELECT * FROM my_table";
$res=odbc_exec($connection,$sql)or die(exit("Error en odbc_exec"));
while($arr = odbc_fetch_array($res)) {
    $var = $arr["OkRef"];
    echo "1.- ".iconv("Windows-1256", "UTF-8", "$var")."<br />";
    echo "2.- ".iconv("CP437", "UTF-8", $var)."<br />";
    echo "3.- ".iconv("CP850", "UTF-8", $var)."<br />";
    echo "4.- ".utf8_decode($arr["OkRef"])."<br />";
    echo "5.- ".utf8_encode($arr["OkRef"])."<br />";
    echo "6.- ".$arr["OkRef"]."<br />";
    echo "7.- ".mb_convert_encoding($arr["OkRef"], "utf-8", "windows-1251")."<br />";
    echo "8.- ".htmlspecialchars( iconv("iso-8859-1", "utf-8", $var) );
    }
}
```

I get this as result:

> 1.- ér    àçHه¬´§d_meta_packet1Y³§0ت.122) ¸ؤ
>
> 2.- Θr    ατHσ¼┤ºd_meta_packet1Y│º0╩.122) ╕─
>
> 3.- Úr    ÓþHÕ¼┤ºd_meta_packet1Y│º0╩.122) ©─
>
> 4.- ?r    ??H????d_meta_packet1Y??0?.122) ??
>
> 5.- ér    àçHå¬´§d_meta_packet1Y³§0Ê.122) ¸Ä
>
> 6.- �r    ��H����d_meta_packet1Y��0�.122) ��
>
> 7.- йr    азHе¬ґ§d_meta_packet1Yі§0К.122) ёД
>
> 8.- ér    àçHå¬´§d_meta_packet1Y³§0Ê.122) ¸Ä

I tried also to add the following (not at once obviously) to make it work as it is:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1');
ini_set('mssql.charset', 'UTF-8');
```

The server is a Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise Edition, and the server Collation is Modern_Spanish_CI_AS.

Comment: Have you read [UTF-8 All the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)? - Ie are you sure the issue is not your PHP character setting or your HTML character setting?

Comment: Martin, thanks a lot for the answer. I am not really sure. As I wrote at the bottom the only things I have tried is changing the header with the meta tag and then the header through PHP.
Also I tried to set the connection to de DB as charset="utf-8" and ISO but that's pretty much it. I'm doing it trying to guess to be honest.

Comment: I tried the conection this way also:
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=$server;Database=$database;Server_CSet=Modern_Spanish_CI_AS ;Client_CSet=Windows-1251;", $user, $password);

Comment: Any suggestion will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know, that this answer is posted too late, but I am in similar situation these days, so I want to share my experience. 
My configuration is almost the same - database and table columns with Cyrillic_General_CS_AS collation. Note, that I use PHP Driver for SQL Server, not build-in ODBC support.

The steps below have helped me to resolve my case. I've used collation from your example.

**Database:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] (
    [TextInSpanish] [varchar](50) COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS NULL,
    [NTextInSpanish] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS NULL
)


INSERT [dbo].[MyTable] (TextInSpanish, NTextInSpanish) 
VALUES ('Algunas palabras en español', N'Algunas palabras en español')
```

**PHP:**

Set `default_charset = "UTF-8"` in your php.ini file.
Encode your source files in UTF-8. I use Notepad++ for this step.

**Read data from database:**

- With default connection encoding. For reading data from database use `$data = iconv('CP1252', 'UTF-8', $data);`
  Note, that by default data is returned in 8-bit characters as specified in the code
  page of the Windows locale that is set on the system. Any
  multi-byte characters or characters that do not map into
  this code page are substituted with a single-byte question
  mark (?) character. This is the default encoding.
- With UTF-8 connection encoding.
  Column must be of type 'nchar' or 'nvarchar'.

**HTML:**

Use: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

**Working Example:**

test.php (PHP 7.1, PHP Driver for SQL Server 4.3, file test.php is UTF-8 encoded):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

<?php
// Connection settings
$server = '127.0.0.1\instance,port';
$database = 'database';
$user = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$cinfo = array(
    "CharacterSet"=>SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR,
    #"CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8",
    "Database"=>$database,
    "UID"=>$user,
    "PWD"=>$password
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $cinfo);
if ($conn === false)
{
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

// Query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";
$res = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if ($res === false) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

// Results
while ($arr = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    # Use next 2 lines with "CharacterSet"=>SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR connection setting
    echo iconv('CP1252', 'UTF-8', $arr['TextInSpanish'])."</br>";
    echo iconv('CP1252', 'UTF-8', $arr['NTextInSpanish'])."</br>";
    # Use next 2 lines with "CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8" connection setting
    #echo $arr['TextInSpanish']."</br>";
    #echo $arr['NTextInSpanish']."</br>";
}

// End
sqlsrv_free_stmt($res);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>

    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience! Never is too late! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Oh my gosh, this did it:
"$data = iconv('CP1252', 'UTF-8', $data);"
Or in my case:

$specialnost = $_POST['specialnost'];

$specialnost = iconv('CP1251', 'UTF-8', $specialnost);

I have been searching for the last three days for a solution! Thank you Zhorov!